# Create an ArrayList with type of an object array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Like the title says, I am trying to instantiate an `ArrayList` with type of a class that I want to be an array. Probably I did not explain it correctly in technical terms, so let's just look at a pseudo code:

```
List<TestClass[5]> lTestList = new ArrayList<TestClass[5]>();
```

Where should I specify the size of the TestClass type array? 
Apologies if my explanation does not make much sense as I am still learning.

Comment: This is a completely unrelated statement, but Java has a restriction that you cannot create an `array` of `generic objects`. For example, you can't make an array of `List<TestClass>` like `List<TestClass>[]`. Of course, you *can* make a List of non-generic arrays, as such, `List<TestClass[]>`. I just figured it's interesting to know in case you didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of a `TestClass` array is `TestClass[]`. So you need to use that as your generic parameter.

```
List<TestClass[]> lTestList = new ArrayList<TestClass[]>();
```

Then when you add items to your list, you can add arrays of the appropriate size.

```
lTestList.add(new TestClass[5]);
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel a bit embarassed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<TestClass[]> lTestList = new ArrayList<TestClass[]>();
```

You shouldn't specify size of array in generic.